# Is it possible to create a Checkbox Selection list using MonoTouch.Dialog?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Basically I want the same functionality that you get by using the RadioSelection attribute except that it allows multiple selections to be made.

Something like this:

```
[CheckSelection]
private IList<int> currentSelections;
private IList<string> myList;
```

Looking at the documentation there doesn't seem to be a mention of anything like this.  So my question is: Can a Checkbox Selection list be created with the present version of MonoTouch.Dialog?  If so, then how?  If not, is there a better way to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to extend MT.Dialog to do this.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought.  Some parts in the source made it seem like this might already be possible so I just wanted to check before I went any further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I used to achieve this:

```
var root new RootElement() { 
    new Section("Bacon"){ 
        new RootElement ("Types", new  RadioGroup (0)){ 
            new Section(){  
                new CheckboxElement ("Smokey"),  
                new CheckboxElement ("Streaky"), 
                new CheckboxElement ("Rasher")
            }   
        }
    } 
};
```

Taken from

> http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/MT-Dialog-multi-select-element-td4516738.html